# Join polygons by groups. What command should I use using dplyr with sf package

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I imported a shp file to R as an sf table and I would like to join my polygons with data.
In just a 2 cases the data relates to an area of a city encompassing several polygons. For instance the data refers to the city with a 6 digits code ending with 1. But I have a map that just in the cases of two towns has town districts and codes ending with range from 2 to 6.

I would like to join these polygons.
First I replace id codes of the city distrct to represent only one code for a town in my data, ending with 1
Then I imagine I should group by the code and join polygons by groups. How can I do that?

```
map_gminy <- 
  map_gminy %>% 
    mutate(
      gmina =
        if_else(str_detect(kod_teryt,"10610"),
                "Łódz",
                gmina),
      kod_teryt =
        if_else(str_detect(kod_teryt,"10610"),
                "106101",
                kod_teryt)
    ) %>% 
      mutate(
      gmina =
        if_else(str_detect(kod_teryt,"12610"),
                "Kraków",
                gmina),
      kod_teryt =
        if_else(str_detect(kod_teryt,"12610"),
                "126101",
                kod_teryt)
      ) %>% 
  group_by(kod_teryt) %>% 
  sf_???????(gemometry)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [st_combine](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_combine.html)?

Comment: @Bas Yes, thank you. I was trying with st_union right and then aggregate I am not versed yet with sf. Thank you again and again. This was what I was looking for.